# mysql - select rows between start year and start month to end year and end month?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to select the rows for given range of year and month. (i.e.: from `<start year>+<start month>` to `<end year>+<end month>`)
I tried the below query but I am getting unexpected rows. Am I missing something?

```
SELECT * FROM table AS t
WHERE 
((YEAR(t.column1)='<start year>' AND MONTH(t.column1)>='<start month>') OR
(YEAR(t.column1)>'<start year>' AND YEAR(t.column1)<'<end year>') OR
(YEAR(t.column1)='<end year>' AND MONTH(t.column1)<='<end month>'))
```

Comment: Aside from comparing numbers to strings, it seems ok. Do you have sample data and the strange output you're getting?

Comment: ain't it easy to store `year+month+(day)` in single `date` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table AS t
WHERE  t.column1
       BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('<start year>', '<start month>', '01'), '%Y%m%d') AND 
               LAST_DAY(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('<start end>', '<start end>','01'), '%Y%m%d'));
```

This will should perform better, as it will use index from column `column1`.

Answer (score 5):

Your query only works correctly if start year and end year are different. If they are the same the query returns all rows from that year. You need to handle this case seperatly:

```
(
    start_year != end_year and 
    (
        (YEAR(t.column1)='<start year>' AND MONTH(t.column1)>='<start month>') OR  
        (YEAR(t.column1)>'<start year>' AND YEAR(t.column1)<'<end year>') OR  
        (YEAR(t.column1)='<end year>' AND MONTH(t.column1)<='<end month>')
    )
)
OR (start_year = end_year and MONTH(t.column1) >= start_month
                          and MONTH(t.column1) <= end_month)
```

However, this can be greatly simplified:

```
YEAR(t.column1) * 12 + MONTH(t.column1) >= start_year * 12 + start_month
and YEAR(t.column1) * 12 + MONTH(t.column1) <= end_year * 12 + end_month
```

or even shorter with `between`:

```
YEAR(t.column1) * 12 + MONTH(t.column1)
BETWEEN start_year * 12 + start_month and end_year * 12 + end_month
```

Comment: @Omesh: You are right, this will make it even shorter. I normally avoid `between`, because to me it sounds like it is exclusive, when in reality it is inclusive. I find that confusing and not explicit enough.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, can you explain the meaning of 12 in the two latter examples?

Comment: A year has twelve months, so this calculates the total number of months

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
... WHERE t.column1>="startYear-startMonth-01" AND t.column1<="endYear-endMonth-31"
```